# Android Universal image loader how to find out file not found in the server when image is not exist

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

In my Android application I need to load and show images from internet so that I use Universal Image loader library to load images. In the application I get image links from json (**some urls do not have images in server**). My problem is the universal image loader throws the FailType.IO_ERROR (fail reason) for both internet problem or the file is not found in the server, **How can I differentiate between internet problem and File not found in the server?**, because I need to show alert only if problem occur by file is not found in the server not by internet problem in the FailType.IO_ERROR (fail reason) category.

This is the code I used for image loading:

```
                    imageLoader.displayImage(linkOfImage, imageView, new ImageLoadingListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String arg0, View arg1) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String arg0, View arg1,
                                FailReason failed) {
                            FailType failType = failed.getType();
                            int failedCode = failType.ordinal();
                            if (failedCode == FailType.IO_ERROR.ordinal()) {
//                           I reach here for both internet and file not found in the server
                            }else if (failedCode == FailType.DECODING_ERROR.ordinal()) {

                            } else if (failedCode == FailType.NETWORK_DENIED.ordinal()) {

                            } else if (failedCode == FailType.OUT_OF_MEMORY.ordinal()) {

                            } else if (failedCode == FailType.UNKNOWN.ordinal()) {

                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String arg0, View arg1, Bitmap arg2) {
            //            ...........
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled(String arg0, View arg1) {

                        }
                    });
```

I listed all FailReason type. I get error code 0 (FailType.IO_ERROR) for both if the image is not present in the server for a particular link or internet is not present.

Please help me to find out the difference between two exceptions, this task is importance to me. thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is your try/catch to catch the exceptions? I see no loader throwing an exception too.

Comment: I did not used try/catch in onLoadingFailed method. please let me know where to put try/catch?

Comment: `Loader throws here exception for both ..`. Is it? Sorry i see no exception thrown. `FailReason failed`. Doesn't it have other members like .getType()? What kind of info is in arg0 and arg1?

Comment: I mean, if image is not present first if condition is executed. it does not throw exception and the arg0 is the image path and arg1 is the image view. please see the edited question.

Comment: Why are you calling that exception if there is no exception? There is no exception. You have a certain FailReason type. Please adapt your post as this is all very confusing.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I listed all FailReason type. I get error code 0 (FailType.IO_ERROR) for both if the image is not present in the server for a particular link or internet is not present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64960/discussion-between-murali-ma-and-greenapps).

Comment: `universal image loader throws the IO exception for both ..`. You are still talking about exceptions instead of FailReason types.

Comment: I am not talking about exception. I list out fail reason. what is the fail reason type for image is not present in the server?

Comment: No? See the subject and intro of your post.

Comment: ok I removed the exception. please see the edited question.

Comment: Ok. `FailReason failed. Doesn't it have other members then .getType()?`. Please answer this. Maybe the reason is in it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get thrown exception by `failReason.getCause()`.

So then you can check `failReason.getCause() instanceof FileNotFoundException` or `failReason.getCause() instanceof SocketTimeoutException`. Something like that.

Comment: But if file does not exists on server it still show cause `FileNotFoundException `. Seems it's not have a solution.